# How to capitalize the first and last letter of a string?

Tags: python, string

So it's not a very difficult problem and I've been trying to do it. Here is my sample code:

```
import sys

for s in sys.stdin:
    s = s[0:1].upper() + s[1:len(s)-1] + s[len(s)-1:len(s)].upper()
    print(s)
```

This code only capitalizes the first letter and not the last letter as well. Any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Yes the first and last letter. Only the first letter is capitalised

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `stdin` and not `input()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are operating on lines, not words, since iterating over `sys.stdin` will give you strings that consist of each line of text that you input.  So your logic won't be capitalizing individual words.

There is nothing wrong with your logic for capitalizing the last character of a string.  The reason that you are not seeming to capitalize the end of the line is that there's an EOL character at the end of the line.  The capitalization of EOL is EOL, so nothing is changed.

If you call `strip()` on the input line before you process it, you'll see the last character capitalized:

```
import sys
for s in sys.stdin:
    s = s.strip()
    s = s[0:1].upper() + s[1:len(s)-1] + s[len(s)-1:len(s)].upper()
    print(s)
```

@Calculuswhiz's answer shows you how to deal with capitalizing each word in your input.

Answer (score 0):

You first have to split the line of stdin, then you can operate on each word using a `map` function. Without splitting, the stdin is only read line by line in the `for` loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

def capitalize(t):
    # Don't want to double print single character
    if len(t) is 1:
      return t.upper()
    else:
      return t[0].upper() + t[1:-1] + t[-1].upper()

for s in sys.stdin:
    splitLine = s.split()
    l = map(capitalize, splitLine)
    print(' '.join(l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBBTsMwELz7FYN6SCIgpeJWiRtHfoB6cOINWeTaxt4Ilc@HTQJUwhfPzM6OvZsuMsbwOM@7m/1U8r7jsE@rZvicYhaUSzHG0YDeJhbr@YtqaY4GenZ4jqESfNogkAgXp84TUmblhcObkn602fZCee3gAZ6CBoALDlsKkEmmHCDtlBLlulll8oX@G14fTr8e3Co9HO8PpxXp/ddthphRwGH5fFvEcdiCSvIsLxwIT9DCwn4e86qcbaqvQ95d3ZtlnaquULXvkUPtm8bMs4yEgcuoKyhw5BdogwOLxjnCx8RCsHBaMIu5s7pTBd8)

Answer (score -1):

You could just use the `capitalize` method for `str` which will do exactly what you need, and then uppercase the last letter individually, something like:

```
my_string = my_string.capitalize()
my_string = my_string[:-1] + my_string[-1].upper()
```